# Нужна альтернатива parse.com

Tags: android, parse.com

Нужна альтернатива parse.com, в связи с его закрытием. Нужно бесплатное облако, похожее на  parse, к-ое умеет отправлять push и имеет (Cloud Code) бэкенд часть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Существует такой сервис https://www.firebase.com. Его не так давно приобрел гугл. На счет пушей не могу скать, то хранить там данные можно.
Возможно получится завести пуши каки-то таким способом https://zapier.com/zapbook/firebase/pushover/

UPD: накнулся на статейку http://apptractor.ru/deploy/baas/7-alternativ-parse.html